# What causes this graphics quality difference between WebGL Build and Unity 5 Editor?

Tags: unity, graphics, lighting, deployment

The Editor version and WebGL version of my Minesweeper clone have some graphics quality differences. I chose 'Fast' option when building this deployment.

Is this the difference between 'Fast' and 'Fastest' options of Optimization Level in Build Settings, meaning that if I choose the 'Fastest' option, the WebGL deployment will be the same as Editor version, unlike below? If not, why this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default settings on the web player are low and on the unity editor are good.

You can go to Edit > Project Settings > Quality, the default settings checkbox is in green light, you can change it in row Default and pressing the dropdown arrow. [image]

Comment: Can you explain in your answer how to change those settings, so that the web deployment is the same as editor?

Comment: At what resolution do you run WebGL?

Comment: Turns out, after the updated settings deployment, I loaded the game from chrome's cache (old copy) for some time and couldn't see the difference. this solved my problem, thanks.